# Altering the height/width of an face loop/ring

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, mesh

How do I alter the height of the face loop in such way that it does not alter dimensions of the other faces, simple the overall height of the object? In other words, it just pushes the other faces away.[image]

Comment: After the selection, how about hiding the faces (H), then hover over the top part and press L (select linked) then move it (G) and unhide (Alt H)

Comment: @Leander So there is no way of doing this whilst keeping the whole object visible?

Comment: These are just workaround, how about go in vertex mode, select the upper edge loop, hide it (H), select the linked top (L), unhide the edge loop (alt h) then move everything. That way, at least everything is visible.

Comment: @Leander Really struggling with this. Am I hiding the upper edge loop of the "row" I want to alter?Not sure what the linked loop is! Aghhhhhh!! Will take a break and work with a fresh head later. Will update then thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the **Pivot point** to **Individual Origins**. Then if you ***Select > Inverse*** and use ***Push/Pull*** it will pull apart the 2 now selected halves, increasing the height of the mesh and stretching the initial face loop.
This might be difficult to do on meshes with complex topologies, though.

Comment: This worked a charm on the cube, I will try it out on the actual mesh I am currently working on. Hopefully its not too complex! Thankyou.